# a href link on img

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hi I have the following code to have few links on top of `img`. It works well in FF but not in IE. It seems IE is not clickable if you put link on top of `img`

```
<div style="z-index:-6755;"><img alt="October Offer" src="images/offers/october-offer.jpg" /></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();" style="text-decoration: none; width: 147px; height: 32px; position: inherit; bottom: 32px; left: 50px; border: 1px solid red; display: block;" target="_parent"> </a> 

<a href="#" onclick="window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();">
<div style="display:block; width: 185px; height: 32px; position: relative; bottom: 50px; left: 260px;border:1px solid blue; ">&nbsp;</div>
</a>
```

Comment: I edited the code. It still doesn't make any sense, so feel free to go and have a look at the source if that makes more sense

Comment: Your HTML code is broken. `<href ...` should be `<a href...` and links (`<a>`) are not allowed to contain block elements such as `div` s.

Comment: href is not an element but an attribute

Comment: @RoToRa @Mark That was my fault actually >< . The OP was using `<aa>` tags so that the parser won't render the code instead of displaying it (he didn't know how to use the code blocks) and I had pressed backspace twice instead of once, biting off that `a` there. I'm truly sorry for the confusion this has caused.

Answer (score 36):

are you just trying to make the image clickable?

you can't have `<href>` that's not a correct html tag.

either place `<img>` inside `<a>` like so: `<a href="http://www.example.com/"><img /></a>`

another way is to set a div with a background image of your image and then a link inside there, make the link display : block and make it the entire width and height of the div and the whole thing will be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an on-click function to img-tag.
Example:
`<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" onclick="home()">`

and then redirect it to a page.

`function home(){ location.replace("/index.html") }`