# How to Place a Hyperlink within a Image Code?

Tags: css, html, image, hyperlink

I am trying to use a Instagram icon as a hyperlink so that when you click on it, it goes directly to my Instagram page. I tested it out on Firefox, and when I click on the icon it doesn't go to my Instagram, it just leaves a blank page.

```
<strong><u>Social Media<u></strong><br>
    <a div class="socialmedia" href="socialmedia">
        <img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram"  
        style="width:30px;height:30px; padding-top: 7px;">
    </a></p>
```

I have a  on it so that I can do a line height code on the icon so it's not too close to the "Social Media" text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a href link on img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779812/a-href-link-on-img)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix an `a` with a `div`.

Try this:

```
<div class="socialmedia">
<a href="socialmedia">
<img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram"  
    style="width:30px;height:30px; padding-top: 7px;">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: *Note, I'm assuming that your href is just a placeholder for the real link and not an error.

Answer (score 0):

You got to remove that div from inside your  element. a link is like this.

```
<strong><u>Social Media<u></strong><br>
  <div div class="socialmedia">
    <a  href="socialmedia">
        <img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram"  
        style="width:30px; height:30px; padding-top:7px;">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: <strong><u>Social Media<u></strong><br>                                            <div class="socialmedia">
    <a href="www.socialmedia.com">
        <img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram"  />
        style="width:30px;height:30px; padding-top: 7px;">
    </a></div>

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. As others have noted, you've got `a` and `div` mixed in together. Your tags, without all the classes and attributes, can basically just be

```
<a><img></a>
```

The reason it's not linking to anything is the `href` - you need to set that to the url of your page. So if your instagram page is `instagram.com/SomeUserName`, you'd do this:

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/SomeUserName" class="socialmedia">
  <img src="images/instagramlogo.png" alt="Instagram"  
    style="width:30px; height:30px; padding-top: 7px;">
</a>
```

Comment: Seems to me that the "socialmedia" link was just a place holder to not reveal exactly what he was linking to.

Comment: Possibly, but no reason to assume, considering the question is specifically "why doesn't this link work?". I haven't tested, but I'm  pretty sure that even with the incorrect `div` attribute on the `a` tag, it would still work if it had a valid url.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is that he was mixing his elements.

Comment: @jack I replaced my codes with yours, and put the actual URL in too. It still doesn't go to the Instagram page though, I'm just getting a blank page like before.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is wrap the img tag with an anchor tag. :)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img 
 src="img.jpg" alt="image"/></a>
```